# Inserting massive number of records into database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to run some algorithms over data massive number of times and store each result in database.

Number of algorithm runs is 80,000-90,000, each cycle takes about 2 seconds (just the algorithm ). 
So it's very time consuming.

My database SQL server 2008.
I want to use ado.net entity framework (is it good for this task it's not good?)
Right now the output data (that needs to be stored in DB) is plain raw (not very big), plus some maintain columns like date and time.

What is the best practice for that?
Insert row by row, as each algorithms completes? store the results in memory and after work is finished insert the data?

Comment: The DB insert is most definitely not a bottleneck here. Just open a connection and insert the result every 2 seconds.

Comment: @leppie, what about EF? is it ok to use it?

Comment: You could. If it is simple, I would probably not even bother  :)

Answer (score 3):

Could you not try BulkInsert after running your algorithm against all records first?
It is very efficient at getting the data into the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Yes it is the best way to import a lot of data in one table

Comment: With perhaps something like `run cycle-send results to thread-goto next cycle` and the thread using BulkInsert to load the data into database.

Comment: so first I need to store the results locally from all algorithms and only after that insert all at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SqlBulkCopy class and use a DataTable as source data. It's realy fast compared with multiple INSERTs.

Comment: but with this, I would have to insert my data into the datatable and only at then end insert it into db, right?

Comment: @jullin - you can create an `IDataReader` version if you don't want a DataTable; easy enough to wrap data as IDataReader

Comment: @Marc Gravell, as I understand I should use SqlBulkCopy to store all data at once, and not row by row after every algorithm run, is it right?

Comment: @jullin - for massive inserts, SqlBulkCopy is an appropriate API. The point I was making is that SqlBulkCopy will accept an IDataReader as an ***input***. You can wrap your local object model (or a stream of objects, if needed) in a hand-cranked IDataReader if that is your intent. DataTable is *easier*, of course - but requires full buffering into a DataTable

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I was reading msdn documentation about SqlBulkCopy, it says: `SqlBulkCopy will fail when bulk loading a DataTable column of type SqlDateTime into a SQL Server column whose type is one of the date/time types added in SQL Server 2008.` but I need to store datetime column...

Comment: @jullin that isn't talking about datetime - it is talking about the new date-only and time-only types. Also: worst-case, you bulk-copy into a staging table *in any format you choose that works*, then process it in an INSERT between the staging table and the target table

Comment: using SQL bulk copy if an error occurrs while importing, how can you check which row number it is ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't use sqlbulkcopy, you could do next:

1. Store data to local variables
2. After all data is collected, begin SQL transaction and insert each row to db. After all insert querys are executed, commit.